# Vuex - setting a new prop

Tags: properties, vuejs2, vuex

I have a vuex store I want to add a new object to it. It is one level down and the prop is called questions. I thought I could use rest/spread and do.

```
 state.assignment = { ...state.assignment, questions: payload}
```

where payload is an array of questions. looking at the documentation this looks like it should work?

Comment: I think doing `state.assignment.questions = payload` should be enough

Comment: does the alternative `Vue.set(assignment, 'questions', payload)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign`

```
const questions = (state.assignment && state.assignment.questions) ? state.assignment.questions : []
const newQuestions = questions.concat(payload) // payload is an array
state.assignment = Object.assign({}, state.assignment, { questions: newQuestions })
```